# Unable to disable TLSv1/TLSv1.1 in Apache 2.4.18

Tags: apache-http-server, ssl

A client has requested that I disable TLSv1 and TLSv1.1 on a web server. The server is running Apache 2.4.8. and OpenSSL 1.0.2g.

I have added the directive to `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ssl.conf`:

```
SSLProtocol TLSv1.2
```

Restarting Apache2 and running a test on SSL Labs (and two other tools) shows that TLSv1 and 1.1 are still enabled. I have tried a lot of variations of the SSLProtocol directive, based on Googling around:

```
SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1.2
SSLProtocol +TLSv1.2 -TLSv1.1 -TLSv1
SSLProtocol +all -TLSv1.1 -TLSv1
```

None of them work. I have also tried adding the directive to `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`. This also makes no difference.

I have no idea how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

> A client has requested that I disable TLSv1 and TLSv1.1 on a web server. The server is running Apache 2.4.8. and OpenSSL 1.0.2g.

Here is the appropriate configuration for what you describe.

```
SSLProtocol             all -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1    
SSLCipherSuite          ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256
SSLHonorCipherOrder     on    
SSLCompression          off    
SSLSessionTickets       off
```

Source: [apache 2.4.18 | modern profile | OpenSSL 1.0.1g](https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/?server=apache-2.4.0&openssl=1.0.1e&hsts=yes&profile=modern)

You can reduce the list of cipher suites to the following:

```
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!RC4
```

Source: [How to force all Apache connections to use TLSv1.1 or TLSv1.2](https://superuser.com/questions/829793/how-to-force-all-apache-connections-to-use-tlsv1-1-or-tlsv1-2/905166#905166)

Answer (score 0):

In Apache, this will not take effect if you have Virtual Hosts enabled.

To resolve the issue, please add the settings onto your Virtual Host files, as this can be controlled for each Virtual Host;

i.e. under /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ you would expect to find multiple files, each is for a web where you can have different settings in each file.

The common setting that does works for me is:

```
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
SSLCipherSuite          ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
SSLSessionTickets off
```